# CRM 2013 export/import accounts to CRM 2015

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have created a test CRM 2015 organization and would like to get all our Accounts and Contacts from our existing CRM 2013 organization.
How can I easily copy this from 2013 to 2015 with reference/relations between Accounts and the Contacs?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SSIS Integration Toolkit for Dynamics CRM](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm/). Recheck [this article](http://danielcai.blogspot.ru/2012/05/use-ssis-to-copy-crm-configuration-data.html).